# Application Failure Detected in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new android development. so I saw video and created this small TIP CALCULATOR. But when I run my app it closes and gives error Application Failure Detected Try Again.
I really want to know where I go wrong in these codes.

I have added two files which are:

**CrazyTipCalc.java**

```
package com.ashish.crazytipcalc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CrazyTipCalc extends Activity {

    private static final String TOTAL_BILL = "TOTAL_BILL";
    private static final String CURRENT_TIP = "CURRENT_TIP";
    private static final String BILL_WITHOUT_TIP = "BILL_WITHOUT_TIP";

    private double billBeforeTip, tipAmount, finalBill;

    EditText billBeforeTipET, tipAmountET,finalBillET;

    SeekBar tipSeekBar;

    private int[] checkListValue = new int[12];

    CheckBox friendlyCB, spacialsCB, opinionCB;

    RadioGroup radioGroup1;

    RadioButton badRadio, goodRadio, bestRadio;

    Spinner problemSpinner;

    Button startButton, pauseButton, resetButton;

    Chronometer timeWaitChronometer;

    long secondsYouWaited = 0;

    TextView timeWatingTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crazy_tip_calc);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            billBeforeTip = 0.0;
            tipAmount = .15;
            finalBill = 0.0;
        }else {
            billBeforeTip = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP);
            tipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP);
            finalBill = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL_BILL);
        }

        billBeforeTipET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
        tipAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipEditText);
        finalBillET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalEditText);

        tipSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.changeTipSeekBar);
        tipSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(tipSeekBarListener);

        billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListener);

        friendlyCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.friendlyCheckBox);
        spacialsCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.spacialCheckBox);
        opinionCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opinionCheckBox);

        setUpIntroCheckBoxes();

        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        badRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.badRadio);
        goodRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.goodRadio);
        bestRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.bestRadio);

        addChangeListenerToRadio();

        problemSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.problemSpinner);
        addItemSelectedListeners();

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButtonTextView);
        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

        setButtonOnClickListener();

        timeWaitChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timeWaitChronometer);
        timeWatingTextView = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timeWaitTextView);

    }

    private TextWatcher billBeforeTipListener = new TextWatcher () {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try{
                billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());       
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                updateTipAndFinalBill();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
             //TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             //TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    private void updateTipAndFinalBill(){
        double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());
        double finalBill = billBeforeTip + (billBeforeTip * tipAmount);
        finalBillET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
        outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
        outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, billBeforeTip);
    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener tipSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            tipAmount = (tipSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;
            tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", tipAmount));
            updateTipAndFinalBill();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
             //TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
             //TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    private void setUpIntroCheckBoxes(){
        friendlyCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                        checkListValue[0] = (friendlyCB.isChecked())?4:0;
                        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();
                        updateTipAndFinalBill();    
            }           
        });

        opinionCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                        checkListValue[2] = (opinionCB.isChecked())?2:0;
                        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();
                        updateTipAndFinalBill();    
            }           
        });

        spacialsCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                        checkListValue[1] = (spacialsCB.isChecked())?1:0;
                        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();
                        updateTipAndFinalBill();    
            }           
        });     
    }

    private void setTipFromWaitressChecklist(){
        int ChecklistTotal = 0;
        for(int item : checkListValue){
            ChecklistTotal += item;
        }
        tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", ChecklistTotal * 0.1));
    }

    private void addChangeListenerToRadio(){
        radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                checkListValue[2] = (badRadio.isChecked())?-1:0;
                checkListValue[3] = (goodRadio.isChecked())?2:0;
                checkListValue[4] = (bestRadio.isChecked())?4:0; 
                setTipFromWaitressChecklist();
                updateTipAndFinalBill();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addItemSelectedListeners(){
        problemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                checkListValue[6] = (problemSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("bad")?-1:0;
                checkListValue[7] = (problemSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("good")?3:0;
                checkListValue[8] = (problemSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("best")?6:0; 
                setTipFromWaitressChecklist();
                updateTipAndFinalBill();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }           
        });
    }

    private void setButtonOnClickListener(){
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;
                String chronoText = timeWaitChronometer.getText().toString();
                String array[]  = chronoText.split(":");

                if(array.length == 2){
                    stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000 +
                            Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
                }else if(array.length == 3){
                    stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                            Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000 + 
                            Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
                }
                timeWaitChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);
                secondsYouWaited = Long.parseLong(array[1]);
                updateTipBasedOnTimeWaited(secondsYouWaited);
                timeWaitChronometer.start();
            }
        });

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeWaitChronometer.stop();

            }

        });

        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeWaitChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                secondsYouWaited = 0;

            }
    });
}

    private void updateTipBasedOnTimeWaited(long secondsYouWaited) {
        checkListValue[9] = (secondsYouWaited > 10)?-2:2;
        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();
        updateTipAndFinalBill();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crazy_tip_calc, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and

**Activity_Crazy_Tip_Calc.XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CrazyTipCalc" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/bill_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/billEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billTextView"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/bill_edit_text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billEditText"
        android:text="@string/tip_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tipEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/tip_edit_text" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/changeTipTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/changeTipTextView"
        android:progress="15" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
        android:text="@string/final_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/finalEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/finalTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/finalTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/final_edit_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/changeTipTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/billEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/change_tip_text_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/introTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/finalEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/intro_text_view" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/opinionCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spacialCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spacialCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/opinion_text_view" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/introTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/introTextView"
        android:text="@string/friendly_text_view" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/spacialCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/spacial_text_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/availTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/introTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:text="@string/available_text_view" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/availTextView"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/badRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/bad_radiobutton" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/goodRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/availTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
        android:text="@string/good_radiobutton" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/problemSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bestRadio"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:entries="@array/problem_solving" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeWaitTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/goodRadio"
        android:layout_below="@+id/problemSpinner"
        android:text="@string/time_waiting_text_view" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/timeWaitChronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bestRadio"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeWaitTextView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/opinionCheckBox"
        android:text="@string/chronometer_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButtonTextView"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/availTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeWaitChronometer"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/start_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spacialCheckBox"
        android:text="@string/reset_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startButtonTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButtonTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spacialCheckBox"
        android:text="@string/pause_button" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bestRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/resetButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/availTextView"
        android:text="@string/best_radiobutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LOGCAT **ERROR**

```
08-03 23:21:33.670: E/ActivityThread(7873): Failed to find provider info for settings
08-03 23:21:39.680: E/ThrottleService(7909): Could not open GPS configuration file             /etc/gps.conf
08-03 23:21:40.530: E/Vold(485): ASEC com.whatsapp.wallpaper-1 already mounted
08-03 23:21:52.380: E/ActivityThread(8387): Failed to find provider info for com.sec.badge
08-03 23:21:55.840: E/ActivityThread(8289): Failed to find provider info for icc
08-03 23:22:45.040: E/PackageManager(7909): Package com.google.android.gms has no     signatures that match those in shared user com.google.uid.shared; ignoring!
08-03 23:25:16.730: E/ThrottleService(8588): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
08-03 23:25:17.180: E/Vold(485): ASEC com.whatsapp.wallpaper-1 already mounted
08-03 23:25:43.060: E/PGA(8588): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
08-03 23:25:43.380: E/ActivityManager(8588): Exception in bstSendTopActivityInfo while sending HttpPost: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:2862 refused
08-03 23:25:43.510: E/ActivityThread(8988): Failed to find provider info for icc
08-03 23:25:43.890: E/ActivityManager(8588): Exception in bstSendTopActivityInfo while sending HttpPost: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:2862 refused
08-03 23:25:44.320: E/PGA(8588): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
```

Comment: can u post logcat plz

Comment: Yes, and please do it as an edit to your question, not putting the code on another site...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not wriiten some methods. I have done that and works perfectly fine.

```
public class CrazyTipCalc extends Activity {

private static final String TOTAL_BILL = "TOTAL_BILL";
private static final String CURRENT_TIP = "CURRENT_TIP";
private static final String BILL_WITHOUT_TIP = "BILL_WITHOUT_TIP";

private double billBeforeTip; // Users bill before tip
private double tipAmount; // Tip amount
private double finalBill; // Bill plus Tip

EditText billBeforeTipET;
EditText tipAmountET;
EditText finalBillET;

private int[] checklistValues = new int[12]; 

CheckBox friendlyCheckBox;
CheckBox specialsCheckBox;
CheckBox opinionCheckBox;

RadioGroup availableRadioGroup;
RadioButton availableBadRadio;
RadioButton availableOKRadio;
RadioButton availableGoodRadio;

Spinner problemsSpinner;

Button startChronometerButton;
Button pauseChronometerButton;
Button resetChronometerButton;

Chronometer timeWaitingChronometer;

long secondsYouWaited = 0;

TextView timeWaitingTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crazy_tip_calc); // Inflate the GUI

    if(savedInstanceState == null){

        // Just started

        billBeforeTip = 0.0;
        tipAmount = .15; 
        finalBill = 0.0; 

    } else {

        // App is being restored

        billBeforeTip = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP);
        tipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP); 
        finalBill = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL_BILL); 

    }

    billBeforeTipET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billEditText); // Users bill before tip
    tipAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipEditText); // Tip amount
    finalBillET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalBillEditText); // Bill plus tip

    tipSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.changeTipSeekBar);

    tipSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(tipSeekBarListener);

    billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListener);

    friendlyCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.friendlyCheckBox);
    specialsCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.specialsCheckBox);
    opinionCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opinionCheckBox);

    setUpIntroCheckBoxes();
    availableBadRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableBadRadio);
    availableOKRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableOKRadio);
    availableGoodRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableGoodRadio);
    availableRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.availableRadioGroup);

    addChangeListenerToRadios();
    problemsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.problemsSpinner);

    problemsSpinner.setPrompt("Problem Solving");

    addItemSelectedListenerToSpinner();

    startChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startChronometerButton);
    pauseChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseChronometerButton);
    resetChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetChronometerButton);

    setButtonOnClickListeners();

    timeWaitingChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timeWaitingChronometer);

    timeWaitingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeWaitingTextView);

}   

private TextWatcher billBeforeTipListener = new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {

        try{

            billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(arg0.toString());

        }

        catch(NumberFormatException e){

            billBeforeTip = 0.0;

        }

        updateTipAndFinalBill();

    }

};
private void updateTipAndFinalBill(){

    double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());

    double finalBill = billBeforeTip + (billBeforeTip * tipAmount);

    finalBillET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
    outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
    outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, billBeforeTip);

}

private SeekBar tipSeekBar;

private OnSeekBarChangeListener tipSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {


        tipAmount = (tipSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;

        tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", tipAmount));

        updateTipAndFinalBill();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};


private void setUpIntroCheckBoxes(){

    friendlyCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

            checklistValues[0] = (friendlyCheckBox.isChecked())?4:0;

            setTipFromWaitressChecklist(); 

            updateTipAndFinalBill();

        }

    });

    specialsCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

            checklistValues[1] = (specialsCheckBox.isChecked())?1:0;

            setTipFromWaitressChecklist();      
            updateTipAndFinalBill();        
        }

    });     

    opinionCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

            checklistValues[2] = (opinionCheckBox.isChecked())?2:0;

            setTipFromWaitressChecklist();      
            updateTipAndFinalBill();

        }       
    });             
}
private void setTipFromWaitressChecklist(){

    int checklistTotal = 0;

    for(int item : checklistValues){

        checklistTotal += item;

    }

    tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", checklistTotal * .01));
}

private void addChangeListenerToRadios(){

    availableRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            checklistValues[3] = (availableBadRadio.isChecked())?-1:0;
            checklistValues[4] = (availableOKRadio.isChecked())?2:0;
            checklistValues[5] = (availableGoodRadio.isChecked())?4:0;              
            setTipFromWaitressChecklist(); 
            updateTipAndFinalBill();                
        }
    });

}

private void addItemSelectedListenerToSpinner(){        
    problemsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            checklistValues[6] = (String.valueOf(problemsSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("Bad"))?-1:0;
            checklistValues[7] = (String.valueOf(problemsSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("OK"))?3:0;
            checklistValues[8] = (String.valueOf(problemsSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("Good"))?6:0;

            setTipFromWaitressChecklist();                      
            updateTipAndFinalBill();            
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }           
    });     
}

private void setButtonOnClickListeners(){   
    startChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

            String chronoText = timeWaitingChronometer.getText().toString();
            String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
            if (array.length == 2) {

              stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
                    + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
            } else if (array.length == 3) {

              stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 
                    + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                    + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
            }

            timeWaitingChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);

            secondsYouWaited = Long.parseLong(array[1]);

            updateTipBasedOnTimeWaited(secondsYouWaited);
            timeWaitingChronometer.start();             
        }                       
    });     
    pauseChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            timeWaitingChronometer.stop();              
        }                       
    });

    resetChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            timeWaitingChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            secondsYouWaited = 0;
        }
    });
}

private void updateTipBasedOnTimeWaited(long secondsYouWaited){

    checklistValues[9] = (secondsYouWaited > 10)?-2:2;

    setTipFromWaitressChecklist(); 

    updateTipAndFinalBill();    
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crazy_tip_calc, menu);
    return true;
}
```